# ¿Hay equivalente en español del inglés 'to have something done', en el sentido de 'encargar'?

Tags: vocabulario

Durante mucho tiempo pensé que se podía usar el verbo 'dejar' con el significado de 'to have something done' en inglés

```
?? Dejé reparar mis zapatos (I had my shoes repaired)
```

para indicar una acción que no haces directamente, sino que encargas a otra persona.

Evidentemente no tenía razón; alguien me ha dicho que me estaba equivocando, además tal definición no existe en el DRAE.

Bien, ¿cómo se puede decir algo así en español?

Seguramente sea la forma de expresar este encargo distinta en una frase como

```
I had my hair cut
```

que

```
I had the buildings constructed in 1985
```

o

```
I had my shoes repaired
```

¿Es la respuesta simplemente 'hacer'? --> 'hice reparar mis zapatos'?

Quizá no haya ningún verbo 'modal' que desempeña este papel, pero quería ver qué pensáis sobre el tema.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Además del verbo "hacer" (hacer hacer algo), existe la posibilidad de usar el verbo "mandar" ([según esta página](https://www.elcastellano.org/saul-ochoa) seguido de preposición "a" y el otro infinitivo en América, y sin preposición mayormente en España):

- Mandé a reparar mis zapatos.
- Mandé reparar mis zapatos.

Además del significado de "ordenar", el verbo "mandar" puede tener la connotación de "enviar" a alguien a hacer algo. Así y todo, es una buena alternativa a "hacer".

El verbo "dejar" podría usarse con un significado relacionado, pero tiene un sentido más locativo (dejar en algún lugar para que lo hagan). Siempre se usa con "a" y el lugar encargado de hacer el trabajo puede mencionarse o no:

- Dejé a reparar mis zapatos (en la zapatería).

Nota: La oración *Dejé reparar mis zapatos* es, aunque extraña, correcta, y significa: Permití que repararan mis zapatos.

Comment: ¿Cómo se dice entonces, "I had my hair cut"? ¿Mandé a cortar el pelo?o ¿Hicé a cortar el pelo?

Comment: @Bluelion7 Con acciones referidas al propio cuerpo, no se usa el causativo: Me corté el pelo (hice que alguien me lo cortara), Me teñí (hice que alguien me tiñera el pelo), Me operé (alguién me operó), Me hice cirugía de nariz (alguien me la hizo)